# Ubuntu .db file: No Application Installed for OLE2 Compound Document Storage

Tags: database, ubuntu, oledb, ole

I am doing a machine Learning project using Columbia Gaze Dataset
http://www.cs.columbia.edu/CAVE/databases/columbia_gaze/

I am using Ubuntu LTS 16.04

There are files like "**Thumbs.db**" and when i try to open them i have error
[No Application For OLE2 Compound Document Storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWOaW.png)

I have also read many other posts but none of them helped

**Is there a tool** to open this .db file(ole2 format) ?

Or must i turn into **Windows10** instead of **Ubuntu**?

*I *tried to do the following* but **without success**:*

1) **ripole tool**(didnt extract to /tmp directory)

2) **JDBC** (to view database with libreoffice base as .odb. Problem with encodings) with **UcanAccess** tool

*I also found the following source codes but couldn't find any solution how to manipulate them*

1) **gfs-html-1.14.42** , **OpenMcdf 2.0** and **oletools-0.46**

Comment: ok i think the problem is that this file is obsolete for Linux, only for windows. It is a compress of all image files in a directory. After a lot of search, i finaly found that tool to view this file
https://thumbsviewer.github.io/